# Pool creates more workers that it is passed by arg

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

The following instruction should creates 8 child process + 1 parent process

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.0 (default, Jun  7 2017, 16:34:33) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from multiprocessing import Pool
>>> pool = Pool(processes = 8)
```

But when I check python process with a monitoring tool  there are 12 process
[image]

Yes, I'm sure that these process were created I ran `pool = Pool(processes = 8)`

SO info:

```
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=debian
```

Comment: tried on ubuntu 16.04; python 3.5.2. creates 8 threads as requested.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist thank you, I updated my question with so information